# Perl CGI scrolling list wont print array of Hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, cgi

I am trying to write a Perl CGI script that prints /etc/passwd users but when I open my CGI my scrolling list just prints out multiple lines of this:

```
"HASH(0x27836d8)"
```

Here is my code where I grab etc passwd and print it to the scrolling list. Can anyone help me out with printing this correctly to the scrolling list?

```
setpwent();
while (@list = getpwent())
{
    ($LOGIN,$PASSWORD,$UID,$GID,$QUOTA,$COMMENT,$GECOS,$HOMEDIR,$SHELL) = @list[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
    if( $UID >= 1001 )
    {
            push @users, { login => "$LOGIN"};
    }
}
endpwent();

print scrolling_list(-name=>'user_list',
                            -values=>[@users],
                            -size=>15);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You gave the list a bunch of hash references, so that's what got displayed. Change

```
push @users, { login => "$LOGIN"};
```

to

```
push @users, $LOGIN;
```

---

```
use strict;
use warnings;

...

setpwent();
while (my @list = getpwent()) {
    my ($user, $uid) = @list[2, 3];
    push @users, $user
        if $ui >= 1001;
}
endpwent();

print scrolling_list(
   -name   => 'user_list',
   -values => \@users,
   -size   => 15,
);
```

Comment: @Trance339, Added a cleaned up version of the code to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As documented in [the CGI perldoc](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MARKSTOS/CGI.pm-3.59/cgi_docs.html), the thing you pass with -values should be a list ref, but you've created a list ref to a list of hashes (due to your use of curly braces above).  Here's a fixed version:

```
    setpwent();
    while (@list = getpwent())
    {
        ($LOGIN,$PASSWORD,$UID,$GID,$QUOTA,$COMMENT,$GECOS,$HOMEDIR,$SHELL) = @list[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
        if( $UID >= 1001 )
        {
                push @users, $LOGIN;
        }
    }
    endpwent();

print scrolling_list(-name=>'user_list',
                            -values=>\@users,
                            -size=>15);
```